# regex REGEXP_SUBSTR split into the columns

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split, substr

Could you please help me to write a regex to split the string into the columns?

Input:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR ('/D 1/D 18/15/1000', xxxx)  from dual ;
```

or

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR ('/D 1/D 18/15', xxxx)   from dual ;
```

Output:

```
col1>D 1<  col2 >D 18< col3 >15<  col4>1000<
```

or

```
col1>D 1< col2>D 18< col3>15<
```

The result should bring columns. So it means I want to split into the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output you are expecting, you don't need to use regex. You can use a simple `REPLACE` to replace the `/` with a space, then trim any spaces from the ends of the string.

```
SQL> SELECT TRIM (REPLACE ('/D 1/D 18/15/1000', '/', ' ')) AS sample_data FROM DUAL;


        SAMPLE_DATA
___________________
D 1 D 18 15 1000


SQL> SELECT TRIM (REPLACE ('/D 1/D 18/15', '/', ' ')) AS sample_data FROM DUAL;


   SAMPLE_DATA
______________
D 1 D 18 15
```

## Update

Based on information in comments, the values should be split into separate columns. The regex below can be used to get the different values by splitting using the `/` as a delimiter.

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS (SELECT '/D 1/D 18/15/1000' AS sample_col FROM DUAL)
  2  SELECT regexp_substr(sample_col, '[^/]+',1,1) as col1,
  3         regexp_substr(sample_col, '[^/]+',1,2) as col2,
  4         regexp_substr(sample_col, '[^/]+',1,3) as col3,
  5         regexp_substr(sample_col, '[^/]+',1,4) as col4,
  6         regexp_substr(sample_col, '[^/]+',1,5) as col5
  7    FROM sample_data;


   COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5
_______ _______ _______ _______ _______
D 1     D 18    15      1000


SQL> WITH sample_data AS (SELECT '/D 1/D 18/15' AS sample_col FROM DUAL)
  2  SELECT regexp_substr(sample_col, '[^/]+',1,1) as col1,
  3         regexp_substr(sample_col, '[^/]+',1,2) as col2,
  4         regexp_substr(sample_col, '[^/]+',1,3) as col3,
  5         regexp_substr(sample_col, '[^/]+',1,4) as col4,
  6         regexp_substr(sample_col, '[^/]+',1,5) as col5
  7    FROM sample_data;


   COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5
_______ _______ _______ _______ _______
D 1     D 18    15
```

Comment: I think, I couldn't explain my problem. The result should bring columns. So it means I want to split into the columns.  D 1 D 18 15 1000 => column1 contains  D1 | column2  D 18 | column3 contains 15 and column4 contains 1000. Split into the columns.

Comment: Just added updated queries that should do what you want.  Please make the output you are looking for clearer in the original question so people don't have to go through the comments to find what your end goal is.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct solution. I will never understand this regex topic. Regards

Comment: If this is the correct solution, please mark the answer as the correct solution so other people aren't wasting their time on a question they think is not answered.

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_SUBSTR` returns the part of the string `subject` that matches the regular expression `pattern`. You  to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` which will allow you to replace a sequence of characters in a string with another set of characters using regular expression pattern matching.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE ('/D 1/D 18/15/1000', '\/(\w+)', '\1')  from dual ;
```